# Save current html state to file via jQuery $.ajax POST to Flask view

Tags: python, flask

Been at this for hours, giving up and posting in the hopes someone can help me out.  Maybe this is a terribly stupid idea but I:

1. Have an html page that I modify using some jQuery controls (adding classes to a large list of items individually on click, filling in textareas, changing page title, etc..
2. On click of a save button want to do something like :

   ```
   $('#save').click(function() {
       myhtml = $('html').html();
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/parse_data",
           data: myhtml
       });
   });
   ```
3. Then on the Python/Flask side:

   ```
   @app.route('/parse_me', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
   def parse_me():
       if request.method == "POST":
           #determine new filename based on #header id
           #save new file with request.form data? request.something data??
           #using the new filename
   ```

I read over the flask docs, and tried many many variations.  I'm thinking my problem primarily lies in how I'm sending & then unpacking the data.  The closest I got was using:

```
data: JSON.stringfy(myhtml)
```

and then on the python side I could "see" that data by doing

```
print request.values
```

inside the parse_me() method. Any help would be appreciated.  It seemed like the "simplest" solution to what I want to accomplish: I modify the dom with jQuery then ship off my changes to flask to package them into a new file on the server.

Comment: What do you mean by "see the data?"

Comment: I could print it, it would show up on my screen with that print commant.  Looks like it was inside of a "MultiDict".

Comment: Sorry, what I should have asked is does the JSON contain all of the data you're interested in? Is this a question of still getting the data or is this a parsing JSON in python question?

Comment: It's a question of getting the data, I don't want it as JSON it's an HTML page.  I'm trying to push the html data from the javascript ajax call to the flask route, then save that data into a new html file. I've never used flask before and don't know anything about moving html content over ajax.

Comment: Would you do me a favor and update your question with what your print looks like. You probably have all the data you want but just not in the format that you desire.

Comment: I was able to get this to work this morning by changing the ajax data call to `data: {html:myhtml}` giving it a key of `html` and myhtml being the actual html content. then on the python side using `data = request.form.get("html").encode("utf-8")` to pull that keys data.. working great now EXCEPT flask is throwing a 500 now, i'll update the message with the response headers that are showing up.

Comment: Add a redirect to /, render a template, or return straight string. Also, add a answer to this question explaining what you did for the next person to have this problem.

Comment: Got it! yes good point, thanks much Rawr for your moral support and solving my 500 problem.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

changed :

```
$('#save').click(function() {
    myhtml = $('html').html();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/parse_data",
        data: {html:myhtml} // made into a hash for retrieval
    });
});
```

on the python side :

```
@app.route('/parse_data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def parse_data():
    # updated: get value for key "html", encode correctly
    data = request.form.get("html").encode("utf-8")
    # do whatever with the data
    return "Data retrieved"
```

Very easy.. loving Flask!